# Why isn't my PHP variable working correctly?

Tags: php, html, variables

I have this code in a config file that is included in the index file:

```
$googleplusurl = '<link rel=”author” href=”https://plus.google.com/b/112742920089284118188/112742920089284118188”/>';
```

That code is called on by this code:

```
<?php echo $googleplusurl;?>
```

But when I go to load the index page, it gives me this:

```
<link rel=â€authorâ€ href=â€https://plus.google.com/b/112742920089284118188/112742920089284118188â€/>
```

What exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: Try using regular quotes. `"` not `”`

Comment: Lots of editors will replace with smart quotes, including TextEdit on OS X. No need to be aggressive @AbraCadaver

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm using Brackets, not MS Word. It must have changed them to that when I copy and pasted it from another file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you have smart quotes `”` instead of normal quotes `"`.